# Retrieving Twitter data on the fly

Tags: python, ruby, curl, twitter

Our company is trying to read in all live streams of data entered by random users, i.e., a random user sends off a tweet saying "ABC company".

Seeing as how you could use a twitter client to search for said text, I labour under the assumption that it's possible to aggregate all tweets that send off ones without using a client, i.e., to file, streaming in live without using hashtags.

What's the best way to do this? And if you've done this before, could you share your script? I reckon the simplest way would be via ruby/python script left running, but my understanding of ruby/python is limited at best.

Kindly help?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a bare minimum:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import twitter
from threading import *
from os import _exit, urandom
from time import sleep
from logger import *
import unicodedata

## Based on: https://github.com/sixohsix/twitter

class twitt(Thread):
    def __init__(self, tags = None, *args, **kwargs):
        self.consumer_key = '...' 
        self.consumer_secret = '...'
        self.access_key = '...'
        self.access_secret = '...'

        self.encoding = 'iso-8859-15'

        self.args = args
        self.kwargs = kwargs

        self.searchapi = twitter.Twitter(domain="search.twitter.com").search

        Thread.__init__(self)
        self.start()

    def search(self, tag):
        try:
            return self.searchapi(q=tag)['results']
        except:
            return {}

    def run(self):
        while 1:
            sleep(3)
```

To use it, do something like:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    t = twitt()
    print t.search('#DHSupport')
    t.alive = False
```

Note: The only reason this is threaded is because it's just a piece of code i had laying around for other projects, it gives you an idea how to work with the API and perhaps build a background service to fetch search results on twitter.
There's a lot of crap in my original code so the structure might look a bit odd.
Note that you don't really need the consumer_keys etc for just a search but you will need OAuth login for more features such as posting or checking messages.

The only two things you really need is:

```
import twitter
print twitter.Twitter(domain="search.twitter.com").search(q='#hashtag')['results']
```

Comment: I've stripped a working copy of my own code that i use in a few projects. However it involves a shit ton of encrypting/decrypting data, posting, logging in via OAuth etc.. so this is the bare minimum to do a query for `#tags` :)

Comment: Doesn't seem to work at my end.AttributeError: 'twitt' object has no attribute 'alive'

Comment: @DustinCurtis Have you installed the mentioned module? https://github.com/sixohsix/twitter

Comment: Did a sudo easy_install twitter on my iMac. I'm assuming it's the same one?

Comment: There is a missing `self.alive = True` before `Thread.__init__(self)`